# Schema.org type for report about lost and found item

Tags: schema.org

I'm developing a kind of lost-and-found website. So, when a person has lost or found something, s(he) will post a report about this.

**How to properly mark up a report about lost/found item, using the Schema.org vocabulary?**

I need to explicitly tell that a publication in question is a report. What `typeof` (RDFa)/`itemtype` (Microdata) are relevant to this kind of post?

Report contains information about:

1. **Items**, that can be things, pets or people;
2. **Contacts** of a person, that is an author of a report in question;
3. **Rewards**, required to get found item back;
4. **Address** of an item;
5. **Date and time** of losing of finding was happen (do not confuse with publication date on server;
6. **Publication date** and time on server.

What attributes should be used to describe such pieces of data?

Comment: Schema.org’s [`Demand`](http://schema.org/Demand) type might be applicable, but it doesn’t offer all properties you need.